# reactjs how to minimize or manage controlled input code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

[I am using reactjs controlled input](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

[reference for below code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41026819/1390678)

```
<input type="text" 
       value={this.state.username}
       onChange={(e) => this.setState({ username: e.target.value })}
       />
```

I want to avoid extra code like `value , onChange` And move them to component like

```
<input type="text" setValueOnChange=(this,'username')/>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried first.

Comment: i don't know if on attribute level we can create component

Comment: "attribute level"? What do you mean?

Comment: I am thinking `setValueOnChange` as component.  what i was able to think is create A whole New component that returns <customInput></customInput>.If i create like this then if future there might be lots of attributes comming

Comment: Eg : like how in angular we create attribute level directives Eg : <input  customValidation/>

Comment: why not using uncontrolled component: `<input ref={el => this.userName=el}/>` and to get it's value use `this.userName.value`.

Comment: @MayankShukla according to research  i did , [controlled input is having lots of benefits](https://goshakkk.name/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/)

Comment: so if i go with uncontrolled input i will have to write more useless code...thats what i want to manage and keep aside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While getting exactly the result you want is not possible, just because it is not a syntactically valid JSX. It is possible to make something looking quite similar to that:

```
// in render
<input type="text" 
  value={this.state.username}
  onChange={setValue(this, 'username')}
/>

// add this method to the component
setValue(propName) {
  return (e) => {
    this.setState({ [propName]: e.target.value })
  }
}
```

You can actually extract the `setValue` function and reuse it with any other component:

```
// in render
<input type="text" 
  value={this.state.username}
  onChange={setValue(this, 'username')}
/>

// somewhere outside of the component
function setValue(component, propName) {
  return (e) => {
    component.setState({ [propName]: e.target.value })
  }
}
```

I believe I've seen some quite popular React forms handling library which was doing exactly this, but in a bit smarter way — they have cached the generated function to avoid creating a bunch of new function objects on each render. Just can't recall how was it named — there are too much new libs in the react world :)